# Drupal Security for specified role

Tags: drupal-7

I'm have some problem with my security.
I want to add security question for administrator of my site and I found "security question" module. It work good, but for autenticated user, not for administrator. I want to check the security question after login for only administrator, not for user.
I try read the .module file of this module, but it's hard to understand.
So, how can I do with that module.
Many thanks!!

Comment: This should ideally go into a patch in the module's issue queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look inside the .module file, you will find this line, line 377

`function _security_questions_user_login(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {`

This is the function where the user login form is altered to include your security question.

What I'd suggest is adding an `if` statement to satisfy your condition, such as:

```
global $user;

// Don't alter form if user isn't an administrator
if (!in_array('administrator', array_values($user->roles))) {
  return;
}
```

Once you've done that, all you need to do is go to the permissions page and **uncheck** the box that allows administrators to **by-pass the security question**.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion but the problem is this module defautly don't add security question for administrator but for any other role. I have 3 roles:'normal user', 'administrator', 'mode' and I dont want to add question to 'normal user'. Can you help me???

Comment: Edited answer, please try again :-)

Comment: Don't forget to up vote and mark my answer as correct. Glad it's sorted mate!